# Carve on/Carve into

Tags: prepositions

Carved **on** the wall of the building was X26.

Carved **into** the wall of the building was X26.

When use the verb carve, do we use it with any other preposition than **into**?

He carved her and his initials on the tree? Or into the tree?

Can carve ever be used with on like we use on with engraved?
**It was engraved on the wall "Brook was here"**, is this a correct construction?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, one says

> He carved his initials *on* the tree.
>   He carved his initials *in* the tree.

[image]

> carved *into* the rock

[image]
<sub>(source: [livescience.com](http://www.livescience.com/images/i/000/031/006/original/shutterstock_62044096.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&downsize=*:1000))</sub>

[image]

> carved *on* the rock

[image]
<sub>(source: [georgiaencyclopedia.org](http://www.georgiaencyclopedia.org/sites/default/files/styles/article-gallery/public/stone%20mountain%20park%20with%20picnic_001.jpg?itok=4jorruBM))</sub>

> carve *up* a turkey

[image]

> **Engraved on**

is correct since it is on the surface.